# How to calculate average price and add other features in future

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to created data frame with unique products and average price for each product.

```
df1
product 1 black 10.0
product 2 grey 20.0
product 2 grey 20.0
product 1 black 20.0
product 1 black 10.0
product 3 red 23.0
product 1 black 10.0
```

I want create dataframe which look like this

```
df2
product 1 black 12.5
product 2 grey 20.0
product 3 red 23.0
```

I tried this, but this it taking too long

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['Product']=df1['Product'].unique()
df2['Color']=df1['Color']

products = data_by_material['Product'].tolist()
product_list = []

for m in range(len(products)):
    product_list.append(df1[df1['Product']==products[m]]['Price'].mean())

df2['Average price'] = pd.concat(product_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

In future a want to add other product features.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is the average price of `product 1 black` 25? `(10+20+10+10)/4 = 12.5`

Comment: IIUC use `df = df.groupby(['Product','Color'], as_index=False)['Price'].mean()`